# Docker containers network: Redis and Custom Image

Tags: python, docker, redis, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am struggling with connecting two container services. Specifically I would like to use a Redis server (https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/) running in one container as: `docker run -d --name my_redis_server redis` and a custom image run like:`docker run -p 8888:8888 --mount type=bind,source=<my_folder>,target=/data/ my_container` build with the following Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml:

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu

ENV PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
ARG PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"

# Updates and tools 
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y gcc make apt-transport-https ca-certificates build-essential git redis-server

RUN apt-get install -y wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget \
    https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && mkdir /root/.conda \
    && bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b \
    && rm -f Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh 

RUN conda --version

# Create conda environment
RUN conda create python=3.6 --name my_env

# Run in a new shell
RUN /bin/bash -c "activate my_env"
RUN <Install some packages>
RUN conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab -y
RUN conda install -c anaconda redis

# The code to run when the container is started:
# Entrypoint
WORKDIR /data/
ENTRYPOINT ["jupyter", "notebook", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--no-browser", "--allow-root"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.3'

services:
   my_container:
     container_name: my_container_env
     build: ./
     restart: always
     ports:
      - '8888:8888'
```

According to my understanding, I should be able to connect from `my_container` (and specifically jupyter) to `my_redis_server` by using either the internal bridge IP (i.e 172.17.0.X) or the docker DNS name (i.e my_redis_server) in both cases by using the standard Redis image port 6379.

Unfortunately, this does not work for me... what am I missing?

Thank you all!

System: Windows 10 - Docker 2.3.0.2

Additional notes:

I did try (as walkaround) to change approach and to connect from `my_container` to the local host Redis server (the compiled WIN version) by running my_container as: `docker run -p 8888:8888 -p 6379:6379 --mount type=bind,source=<my_folder>,target=/data/ my_container` and connecting from the jupyter inside the container to the local host as `127.0.0.1:6379`, this did not work neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified which method you are exactly following. In Both cases, the issue arose because of network not being defined.  In the `docker run` method as specified in the beginning, you need to specify the network by using `--network=<network_name>`. This network can be a default bridge network, user-defined bridge network, host network, or none. Be sure about what to use as all of them have their own purpose and disadvantages.

In `docker-compose` way I believe you still run Redis using `docker run` and `my_container` in docker-compose which results in both the containers being connected to different networks. So here you need to run Redis also using the same compose.

Updated docker-compose:

```
version: '2.3'

services:
   my_container:
     container_name: my_container_env
     build: ./
     restart: always
     ports:
      - '8888:8888'
   redis:
     container_name: my_redis_server
     restart: always
     ports:
      - 6379:6379
```

References:

1. [Networking overview](https://docs.docker.com/network/)
2. [Use bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/)
3. [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Comment: Thanks, I did adjust the docker-compose as advised, I was able to connect to the Redis container by using this connection test [link](https://enterprise-docs.anaconda.com/en/latest/data-science-workflows/data/redis.html) by changing the host with the name of the container.